# bambuser ffmpeg on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

Basically, I need to combine(append) audio files in android. This is required to perform pause / resume function for a voice recorder.

I have successfully compiled bambuser ffmpeg on Android with the following.

```
1. Oracle Virtual Box
2. Ubuntu 12.04 x86
3. android-ndk r8
4. Archive for client versions 1.3.7 to 1.6.6
```

(from bambuser http://bambuser.com/opensource)

I have changed the package name in build.sh to suit my package name.
After building, I have got the ffmpeg from build folder with the following structure

ffmpeg

```
-armeabi
-armeabi-v7a
```

I have copied the ffmpeg folder into my project/jni folder in my windows machine.

Created a `native.c` file to include the necessary libs. 
Made `ndk-build`. Got the `.so` file.
 When I try to do this in android activity,

```
            try {
        System.loadLibrary("FFmpegTest");   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
          File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard");
   Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -i test.wav test1.wav",null,dir);
try {
     p.waitFor();
}  catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the following error.

```
05-31 11:57:53.532: D/dalvikvm(278): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.ffmpegtest/lib/libFFmpegTest.so 0x43e37a88

05-31 11:57:53.532: D/dalvikvm(278): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.ffmpegtest/lib/libFFmpegTest.so 0x43e37a88

05-31 11:57:53.532: D/dalvikvm(278): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.ffmpegtest/lib/libFFmpegTest.so 0x43e37a88, skipping init

05-31 11:57:53.562: W/System.err(278): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [ffmpeg, -i, test.wav test1.wav] Working Directory: /mnt/sdcard Environment: null
```

Can anyone guide me the procedure ?

Comment: @ Andy Developer i'm trying to build ffmpeg from my windows os with the help of virtualBox using ubuntu can you please give me the steps what are the things should i download and to build it

Comment: i'm trying to build ffmpeg from my windows os with the help of virtualBox using ubuntu can you please give me the steps what are the things should i download and to build it

Answer (score 0):

I think you do no need any `*.so`.

You , probably, should compile `ffmpeg` binary for Android.

Then put the binary into you `res/raw` folder.

Then, upon first execution, your program should copy it from the `res/raw` to the app's dir and set `chmod +x` on it.

Then you can call ffmpeg binary with `System.exec` or the like.

It worked for me fine. I have used the code here `https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264` as an example.